# Return type of union

Tags: c, unions

I have this union declaration:

```
typedef union
{
  float number;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
} SensorReadings;
```

And then I have an array of these unions.

```
SensorReadings EnergyMeterReadingsArray[6];
```

If I want to return `EnergyMeterReadingsArray[0].number;` then the return type should be a `SensorReadings` or `float`?

Comment: If you only want to return the `float` value the return type must be `float`.

Comment: Thanks! You can do a proper answer so I can upvote and mark it as the selected answer.